# Instagram Webhook subscription fails

Tags: facebook-graph-api, webhooks, instagram-api, instagram-story

I am trying to enable an Instagram story_insights webhook on a live Facebook App. I am able to receive test data successfully, but won't receive any live data.

The webhook has been configured via the Facebook App Dashboard for an app with both "manage_pages" and "instagram_manage_insights" permissions granted.

I tried to perform a POST request to the {page-id}/subscribed_apps endpoint but couldn't subscribe to the instagram story insights as there is no related subscribed_field.

Is registering the webhook in the app dashboard sufficient to receive data, or do I need to perform some kind of registration for each Facebook Page connected to an Instagram Business account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks/

> With Graph API version 3.2, the /{page-id}/subscribed_apps edge now requires the subscribed_fields parameter, which currently doesn't support Instgram webhooks fields. To get around this, use an older version of the API, or include the subscribed_fields parameter with a non-Instagram field, then unsubscribe from the field later using your app's dashboard.

Just use some field that will most likely not change from your Facebook Page, like "email".

Comment: I tried this approach, but sending a POST request to that endpoint does not produce as an effect the subscription to story_insights, only to the field(s) passed as parameter.

Comment: did you follow all the steps in the link of my answer carefully? it works perfectly fine for me, i am using it for story insights too. you do know that you can only get the insights once after 24 hours, right? also, you cannot get insights of reposts, only new story elements. try if you get the stories with the /stories endpoint too - of course you only get the current ones that are not gone already.

Comment: @luschn I'm having the same problem as OP. I got a {"Success": true} from posting to the endpoint and subscribing to the email field, still nothing is firing. I'm using API v3.3 and have instagram_basic, instagram_manage_insights and manage_pages permissions. Did I miss anything?

Comment: are you sure you do not get anything? did you set up the webhook correctly in the app settings? can you log the post request you should get directly? maybe there is something wrong with the code in the webhook post area.

Comment: Webhook worked perfectly when I tried to test it from App Dashboard, but never received story_insights calls from Facebook. The App is in Live mode. When I subscribed for email using page token with POST {page-id}/subscribed_apps - then FB started sending story_insights to the webhook. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

From the API docs it says ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks )

> Technically it doesn't matter which Page Field you subscribe to. Your app will not receive notifications of changes to that field unless you configure Page subscriptions in the App Dashboard and subscribe to that field.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to subscribe on page level through api was giving error, just subscribing 'story_insights' on app worked for me.
After this, story insight started coming on their own.

Comment: Please support your answer with a code, image or link to the documentation.